# bash array not be properly processed when mapfile is used to read in values

Tags: bash, array

this one has me baffled.

Here are 2 versions of loading a bash array, one works, the other does not.

If I explicitly initialize the array within the script, it works fine:

```
zz=( 1 26 32 54 71 13 30 43 52 73 7 23 42 57 61 15 27 35 56 66 5 20 36 51 68 )

#print in reverse
for i in {24..0}
do
        echo "zz[$i] is ${zz[$i]}"
done
```

Output as expected:

```
zz[24] is 68
zz[23] is 51
zz[22] is 36
zz[21] is 20
zz[20] is 5
zz[19] is 66
zz[18] is 56
zz[17] is 35
zz[16] is 27
zz[15] is 15
zz[14] is 61
zz[13] is 57
zz[12] is 42
zz[11] is 23
zz[10] is 7
zz[9] is 73
zz[8] is 52
zz[7] is 43
zz[6] is 30
zz[5] is 13
zz[4] is 71
zz[3] is 54
zz[2] is 32
zz[1] is 26
zz[0] is 1
```

This version does not work properly (at the moment):

```
# cat your_data
1 26 32 54 71 13 30 43 52 73 7 23 42 57 61 15 27 35 56 66 5 20 36 51 68
```

```
mapfile -t zz < your_data

#print in reverse
for i in {24..0}
do
        echo "zz[$i] is ${zz[$i]}"
done
```

```
Output:
zz[24] is
zz[23] is
zz[22] is
zz[21] is
zz[20] is
zz[19] is
zz[18] is
zz[17] is
zz[16] is
zz[15] is
zz[14] is
zz[13] is
zz[12] is
zz[11] is
zz[10] is
zz[9] is
zz[8] is
zz[7] is
zz[6] is
zz[5] is
zz[4] is
zz[3] is
zz[2] is
zz[1] is
zz[0] is 1 26 32 54 71 13 30 43 52 73 7 23 42 57 61 15 27 35 56 66 5 20 36 51 68
```

So when the data is read in via mapfile, it all gets stuffed in zz[0]. Even if I explicitly set IFS to space only (" "). I am pretty sure this was working at some point so maybe it is something in my environment. I am stumped...

Thanks,
Snarksdad

Answer (score 2):

The `mapfile` command reads the file line-wise, i.e. expects them separated by `\n`. Since you have the data space-separated, this (only) line in your file is taken as one single token and consequently assigned to the first array position. Try changing your input file as in

```
1
26
32

...

68
```

It should to the trick.

Comment: Or set a new delimiter with `mapfile -d`?

Comment: Huh! I didn't know about that one. Can you point to documentation concerning this, none of the article I found mentioned it.

Comment: You'll get a newline in the last position of the array though... Maybe better to read it from `tr ' ' '\n'` or something?

Comment: Thanks AdminBee, That does work though every thing I have read about mapfile led me to believe it would adhere to the IFS settings.

Comment: Kusalananda, my bash/mapfile does not support a -d option,  neither cygwin or my linux distro. If a later version has this option, it is long overdue...Thanks.

Comment: It seems the -d option was introduced in bash version 4.4

Comment: @Snarksdad You're welcome. If you found the answer useful, please consider accepting it so that others facing a similar problem may find it more easily. Also, if you have suggestions for improving the answer, please let me know.

Answer (score 1):

If all your data is in one space-separated line in the file, do this:

```bsh
read -r -a arrayname < filename
```

The -a is the key here: read a line from the file, split it according to $IFS, and store the fields in the array.

As has been pointed out, mapfile splits the file by *lines* not by *words*.